# PrimeFaces 5.2: How to render Element that dependent on different contexts?

Tags: dom, primefaces, jsf-2, parent, rendered-attribute

Let's say: For repeatable code fragment reuse in different context. I had a fragment.xhtml will be included in multiple other different xhtml, say main1.xhtml and main2.xhtml

fragment.xhtml as:

```
<h:body>
  <p:panelGrid id="qualifyGrid">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="4">#{staffBean.currentStaff.name} Qualify</p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>
   ......
    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="addlabel"><h:outputLabel for="id" value="#{clientqualify['web.qualify.label.id']}"/></p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="wideField" colspan="3">
            <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{qualifyvalue1}" rendered=""/>
            <h:inputText id="id" value="#{qualifyvalue}" rendered=""/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
   ......
    <p:row>
        <p:column styleClass="addlabel"><h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{clientqualify['web.qualify.label.name']}"/></p:column>
        <p:column styleClass="wideField" colspan="3"><p:inputText styleClass="field" id="name" value="#{qualifyControlBean.currentQualify.qualifyName}" required="true"/></p:column>
    </p:row> 
  </p:panelGrid>
</h:body>
```

main1.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
  <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/ozssc-staff-template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h3>#{clientqualify['web.qualify.edit.heading']}</h3>
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />
        <h:form id="qualifyeditform" prependId="false">
            <ui:include src="fragment.xhtml"/>
            <h:panelGrid style="display:block" border="0">
                <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save" action="#{qualifyControlBean.saveQualify}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-save" ajax="false" disabled="#{qualifyControlBean.currentQualify.status=='Verified'}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

main2.xhtml

```
<h:body>
  <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/ozssc-staff-template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h3>#{clientqualify['web.qualify.edit.heading']}</h3>
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />
        <h:form id="qeditform" prependId="false">
            <ui:include src="fragment.xhtml"/>
            <h:panelGrid style="display:block" border="0">
                <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save" action="#{qualifyControlBean.saveQualify}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-save" ajax="false" disabled="#{qualifyControlBean.currentQualify.status=='Verified'}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

from above snippets you saw, the fragment.xhtml was included into two different forms, in main1.xhtml, form id is "qualifyeditform" and in main2.xhtml, form id is "qeditform".

I am having difficult to find a way to let fragment.xhtml element rendering different input text by different parent context. i.e. if this fragment.xhtml was included into main1.xhtml (that in form id as: "qualifyeditform"), render inputText id "id1". If this fragment.xhtml was included into main2.xhtml (that in form id as: "qeditform") render inputText id "id".

How I can set The EL expression to find the parent form element's id? and use it in my rendered="" expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do

```
<h:inputText id="id1" 
             value="#{qualifyvalue1}" 
             rendered="#{component.parent.clientId eq 'qualifyeditform'}"/>
```

Comment: Eventually. By using rendered="#{component.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.clientId eq 'qualifyeditform'}"